# How can I add a random binary info into current 'coordinate'? (Python)

Tags: python, list, random, binary, tuples

This is part of the code I'm working on: (Using Python)

```
import random
pairs = [         
(0, 1),
(1, 2),
(2, 3),
(3, 0),    # I want to treat 0,1,2,3 as some 'coordinate' (or positional infomation)
]
alphas = [(random.choice([1, -1]) * random.uniform(5, 15), pairs[n]) for n in range(4)]
alphas.sort(reverse=True, key=lambda n: abs(n[0]))
```

A sample output looks like this:

```
[(13.747649802587832, (2, 3)),
 (13.668274782626717, (1, 2)),
 (-9.105374057105703, (0, 1)),
 (-8.267840318934667, (3, 0))]
```

Now I'm wondering is there a way I can give each element in 0,1,2,3 a random binary number, so if [0,1,2,3] = [0,1,1,0], (By that I mean if the 'coordinates' on the left list have the corresponding random binary information on the right list. In this case, coordinate 0 has the random binary number '0' and etc.) then the desired output using the information above looks like:

```
[(13.747649802587832, (1, 0)),
 (13.668274782626717, (1, 1)),
 (-9.105374057105703, (0, 1)),
 (-8.267840318934667, (0, 0))]
```

Thanks!!

Comment: I'm not clear on how you got to your output or what you mean by "if [0,1,2,3] = [0,1,1,0]"

Comment: @busybear Thanks for the comment! By "if [0,1,2,3] = [0,1,1,0]" , I mean if the 'coordinates' on the left list have the corresponding random binary information on the right list. In this case, coordinate 0 has random binary number '0' and etc. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Sorry but I'm still not clear on how that gets you to your desired output

Comment: @busybear The elements in each tuple are just replaced by the random binary number. Here, since 1 = '1', 2 = '1', 3 = '0', so (2,3) = (1,0), and (1,2) = (1,1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way using `dict`:

```
d = dict(zip([0,1,2,3], [0,1,1,0]))

[(i, tuple(d[j] for j in c)) for i, c in alphas]
```

Output:

```
[(13.747649802587832, (1, 0)),
 (13.668274782626717, (1, 1)),
 (-9.105374057105703, (0, 1)),
 (-8.267840318934667, (0, 0))]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function to convert your number to the random binary assigned. Using a dictionary within this function would make sense. Something like this should work where `output1` is that first sample output you provide and `binary_code` would be `[0, 1, 1, 0]` in your example:

```
def convert2bin(original, binary_code):
    binary_dict = {n: x for n, x in enumerate(binary_code)}
    return tuple([binary_code[x] for x in original])

binary_code = np.random.randint(2, size=4)
[convert2bin(x[1], binary_code) for x in output1]
```